# Search not working when selecting multiple value from drop in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, html-select

I am trying to search by selecting multiple value from drop down list. But its only showing result for  last entered/selected value from drop down list rather then for all the selected value. here is my code

Search form

```
<form  method="post" action="search1.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
    <label for = "city">Countries</label>
    <select name="name" id="name" multiple>
        <option value="0">Select Title</option>
        <?php
        include('config.php');
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM student_record");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</div>
</form>
```

MYsql Query

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
require_once "config.php";
$sql="SELECT  id, name, address, marks FROM student_record Where name LIKE '%".$name."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In server code, please check $name

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
var_dump($name)
```

1. if it is array, you can use following code

```
    $searchStr = implode(",", $name);
    $sql = "ELECT  id, name, address, marks FROM student_record Where FIND_IN_SET(name, '{$esarchStr}') > 0";
```

2. If it is comma seperated string, you can use following code

```
    $sql = "SELECT  id, name, address, marks FROM student_record Where FIND_IN_SET(name, '{$name}') > 0";
```

Comment: solved, you are Genius. Lot of thanks sir

Comment: Solved with SQL injection. Genius, indeed

Comment: That is this wide open for SQL injection, that's the problem.

Comment: Can't see how this supposedly solved the problem in the first place though. `$_POST['name']` should not be an array here, even if multiple options were selected - because PHP _overwrites_ multiple external parameters with the same name, unless "square bracket syntax" is used in the parameter name. It would have to be `<select name="name[]"`. If OP is getting an array already with just `name="name"` - then I suppose this can't have been a normal form submission, but some JS must be involved.